# How to make pagination in java swing using combo box?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, pagination

I want to make pagination in java swing with combo box as parameter to define the amount of the row that will display and I use button next, previous, back, last too ..

Here is the code :

```
view.getBtnNextPage().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String c = String.valueOf(view.getComboBox().getSelectedItem());

            int a = view.getTable().getRowCount();
            int b = (int) Biodata.countBiodatas();
            if (c.equals("5")) {

                int item = b * a;// 3
                int next = item * a;
                int akhir = b - a;

                refreshTable(Biodata.findBiodataEntries(a + 5 - 5,
                        a + 5 + 6));

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: AWT or Swing? *"so can anyone help me ?"*  Can you show us [what you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)?  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Swing 

view.getBtnNextPage().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String c = String.valueOf(view.getComboBox().getSelectedItem());
    
    int a = view.getTable().getRowCount();
    int b = (int) Biodata.countBiodatas();
    if(c.equals("5")){
     
     int item = b*a;//3
     int next = item*a;
     int akhir = b-a;
     
     
     refreshTable(Biodata.findBiodataEntries(a+5-5, a+5+6));
     
    } 
  }});

Comment: 1) Please don't put code in comments.  Edit it into the question and use code formatting.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) I asked 2 questions and got one answer.  Please pay attention.